# Key error in dna complement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

```
import string
import os,sys

file=open("C:\Python27\\New Text Document.txt",'r')\
seq =file.readlines() basecomplement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}

def translate(seq):
    aaseq = []
    for str in seq:
       aaseq.append(basecomplement[str])
    return aaseq

for frame in range(1):
    rseqn= (''.join(item.split('|')[0] for item in translate(seq[frame:])))

rseqn = rseqn[::-1]    
print(rseqn)
print(seq)
```

ERROR HERE IS   File

```
"C:\Users\ram\Desktop\pythonhw\dnacomp.py", line 13, in <module>
rseqn= (''.join(item.split('|')[0] for item in
translate(seq[frame:])))   File

"C:\Users\ram\Desktop\pythonhw\dnacomp.py", line 10, in translate
aaseq.append(basecomplement[str]) KeyError:
'AGTCTGGCATACCAGTACAGACTATCA'
```

if i use simple string i am also getting sequence but i tried to read the file as input it shows the following error

Comment: please clean the code !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to get at

```
def translate(seq):
    basecomplement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
    return ''.join(basecomplement[letter] for letter in seq)
```

Testing

```
s = 'ATCGGCATAATAC'
>>> translate(s)
'TAGCCGTATTATG'
```

For translating a file, you would do something like

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(translate(line))
```

Comment: i understand can i use this function for file as input Cyber

Comment: Can you show an example of what your file looks like?

Comment: dna file FASTA formate

Comment: if you want me to paste data here i can do it also

Comment: i have to use this code in shell or in program